# How to make nested functions public?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function example(){
        alert('Example');
    };
});
<a href='javascript:example();'/>
```

My problem is that the link won't call the function.
I believe it's because `example()` is nested within another function.
How do I fix this, without removing `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Place it outside document.ready. function declaration don't have to go in there.

Comment: You can assign it to a global variable from inside the `ready` handler. But really, you should get rid of `javascript`-pseudo-inline-handlers and attach the listener properly instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the function declaration outside of the `document.ready` block.

Even if `example()` uses the DOM, the actual *creation* of the function doesn't need the DOM to be ready. And anyway, logically speaking, by the time the link is interactive, the function will have to have loaded.

Comment: Ah, alright. I was under the impression that, since one part of my code needed the page to be loaded, everything else did, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
function example(){
   alert('Example');
};
<a href='javascript:example();'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GnrVh/1/)**
  try in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   function example() {
       alert('Example');
   }

   $("a").on("click", example);
```

});